# API 1.1 requesting twitter bearer token using r

Tags: r, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I have searched this forum and tried several things that seemed relevant, but with no success. If anyone can spot what I'm missing I would be very grateful.

I am trying to get a bearer token using application only authorization as explained at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth so that I can GET follower s/ids.

I have constructed a request in r using rstudio with my consumer key & secret in Base64 encoded form.

```
library(httr)
POST(url="https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token", config=add_headers(
c('Host="api.twitter.com"',
'User-Agent="NameOfMyApp"',
'Authorization="Basic MyKeyandSecretBase64Encoded"',
'Content-Type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"',
'Content-Length="29"',
'Accept-Encoding="gzip"')), body="grant_type=client_credentials")
```

In response I receive:

```
Response [https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token]
Status: 403
Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
{"errors":[{"label":"authenticity_token_error","code":99,"message":"Unable to verify your credentials"}]}
```

I tried resetting my credentials but it made no difference.

Comment: Could you please show me where did you have your secret and secret code in your request in order to get the bearer token from the authentication server? Thanks,
Mig

Answer (score 1):

I'm a few weeks late, but for anyone like me who stumbles across this page, here is some code that works for me, returning a bearer token:

```
POST(url="https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token",
config=add_headers(c("Host: api.twitter.com",
"User-Agent: [app name]",
"Authorization: Basic [base64encoded]",
"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
"Content-Length: 29",
"Accept-Encoding: gzip")),
body="grant_type=client_credentials")
```

Once you have a bearer token, you put it in the header of a GET like so:

```
GET("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=justinbieber&count=5000",
config=add_headers(c("Host: api.twitter.com",
"User-Agent: [app name]",
"Authorization: Bearer [bearer token]",
"Accept-Encoding: gzip")))
```

Comment: What was the problem? Both codes (your question and answer) appears to be the same...

Answer (score 1):

A late response, but the existing answer wasn't working for me. So here's a solution with a modification of the `GET` request.

`add_headers()` uses a named vector. This requires the hyphenated header names to be bracketed with backticks (``). So your `POST()` call should be:

```
response <- POST(url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token",
                 config = add_headers(.headers = c(Host = "api.twitter.com",
                                                   `User-Agent` = "NameOfMyApp",
                                                   Authorization = "Basic [base64encoded]",
                                                   `Content-Type` = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
                                                   `Content-Length` = "29",
                                                   `Accept-Encoding` = "gzip")),
                 body = "grant_type=client_credentials")
```

Within a successful response the application access token can be accessed with:

```
bearer_token <- jsonlite::fromJSON(rawToChar(response$content))$access_token
```

You can then verify this with a `GET` request, such as:

```
GET("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=justinbieber&count=100",
    config = add_headers(.headers = c(Host = "api.twitter.com",
                                      `User-Agent` = "NameOfMyApp",
                                      Authorization = paste("Bearer", bearer_token),
                                     `Accept-Encoding` = "gzip")))
```